# Excel basic football table from results including assigning points

Tags: python, excel

I continue my Python learning, and have reached an impasse and struggling to find an answer online.

I have imported a baisc excel sheet (to use as an easy dataset) and applied the following code to get this table:

```
#get dataframe

df=pd.read_excel('example.xlsx','Games',header=0)
print(df.columns,'+\n')
mapping = {df.columns[0]:'Home Team',df.columns[1]:'Home Score',df.columns[2]:'V',df.columns[3]:'Away Team',df.columns[4]:'Away Score'}
df = df.rename(columns=mapping)



#assign winners for the games


def Win_check(df):
    if df['Home Score'] >= df['Away Score']:
        return ('HW')
    elif df['Home Score'] <= df['Away Score']:
        return ('AW')
    else:
        return ('Dr')
    


#this line adds the new column
df['Win_Check'] = df.apply(Win_check, axis=1)
#print(df[['Home Score','Away Score','Win_Check']])
print(df)
```

```
  Home Team  Home Score  V Away Team  Away Score Win_Check
0         A           2  v         B           1        HW
1         C           1  v         D           3        AW
2         A           2  v         C           1        HW
3         D           3  v         B           3        HW
4         A           0  v         D           2        AW
5         B           0  v         C           2        AW
```

SO my question is how do I take the result and assign points to each team, and then finally tabulate those results into a league table?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get. Better show (as text) expected result.

Comment: in `Win_check()` you should use `<` and `>` instead of `<=` and `>=`. With currrent code it will never return `'Dr'`

Comment: simpler: `read_excel(..., names=['Home Team', 'Home Score', 'V', 'Away Team', 'Away Score')`, Eventually it may need `skiprows=1` to skip first row with old names. Doc [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: The result im looking for would be:

Team Pts
A        6

Comment: To clarify in the first line of the table id like to assign Team A (as the winner) 3 points, and line two the same to Team C.

Then add these into a new table once each game is assigned points

Comment: why it result is `Team Pts A`? How do you calculate it? You could describe it in question -so other people will see it.

Comment: you can use `groupby("Home Team")` to create groups and in every group count how many times it gets `HW`. And the same for `groupby("Away Team")`

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `Home Team` and in every group count how many times it get `HW`. And the same do for `Away Team`

```
text = '''HomeTeam  HomeScore  V AwayTeam  AwayScore
A           2  v         B           1
C           1  v         D           3
A           2  v         C           1
D           3  v         B           3
A           0  v         D           2
B           0  v         C           2
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+', names=['Home Team', 'Home Score', 'V', 'Away Team', 'Away Score'], skiprows=1)
print(df)

def win_check(row):
    if row['Home Score'] > row['Away Score']:
        return 'HW'
    
    if row['Home Score'] < row['Away Score']:
        return 'AW'
    
    return 'Dr'

df['Win_Check'] = df.apply(win_check, axis=1)
print(df)

# ----

points = {}

for team, group in df.groupby('Home Team'):
    print('--- Home Team:', team, '---')
    print('HW:', sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'HW'))
    print('AW:', sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'AW'))
    print('Dr:', sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'Dr'))

    if team not in points:
        points[team] = 0

    points[team] += 3 * sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'HW')

for team, group in df.groupby('Away Team'):
    print('--- Away Team:', team, '---')
    print('HW:', sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'HW'))
    print('AW:', sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'AW'))
    print('Dr:', sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'Dr'))

    if team not in points:
        points[team] = 0
        
    points[team] += 3 * sum(group['Win_Check'] == 'AW')
    
print('points:', points)
```

Result:

```
--- Home Team: A ---
HW: 2
AW: 1
Dr: 0
--- Home Team: B ---
HW: 0
AW: 1
Dr: 0
--- Home Team: C ---
HW: 0
AW: 1
Dr: 0
--- Home Team: D ---
HW: 0
AW: 0
Dr: 1
--- Away Team: B ---
HW: 1
AW: 0
Dr: 1
--- Away Team: C ---
HW: 1
AW: 1
Dr: 0
--- Away Team: D ---
HW: 0
AW: 2
Dr: 0
points: {'A': 12, 'B': 0, 'C': 3, 'D': 6}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you should do it directly in `Win_Check`

```
text = '''HomeTeam  HomeScore  V AwayTeam  AwayScore
A           2  v         B           1
C           1  v         D           3
A           2  v         C           1
D           3  v         B           3
A           0  v         D           2
B           0  v         C           2
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+', names=['Home Team', 'Home Score', 'V', 'Away Team', 'Away Score'], skiprows=1)
print(df)

points = {}

def win_check(row):
    if row['Home Team'] not in points:
       points[ row['Home Team'] ] = 0

    if row['Away Team'] not in points:
       points[ row['Away Team'] ] = 0


    if row['Home Score'] > row['Away Score']:
        points[ row['Home Team'] ] += 3
        return 'HW'
    
    if row['Home Score'] < row['Away Score']:
        points[ row['Away Team'] ] += 3
        return 'AW'
    
    return 'Dr'

df['Win_Check'] = df.apply(win_check, axis=1)
print(df)
    
print('points:', points)
```

Result:

```
  Home Team  Home Score  V Away Team  Away Score
0         A           2  v         B           1
1         C           1  v         D           3
2         A           2  v         C           1
3         D           3  v         B           3
4         A           0  v         D           2
5         B           0  v         C           2

  Home Team  Home Score  V Away Team  Away Score Win_Check
0         A           2  v         B           1        HW
1         C           1  v         D           3        AW
2         A           2  v         C           1        HW
3         D           3  v         B           3        Dr
4         A           0  v         D           2        AW
5         B           0  v         C           2        AW

points: {'A': 6, 'B': 0, 'C': 3, 'D': 6}
```

Comment: Great answer, but how to change this:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+', names=['Home Team', 'Home Score', 'V', 'Away Team', 'Away Score'], skiprows=1)
print(df)

to read the excel file!!!

Comment: use `read_excel('example.xlsx', ...)` instead `read_csv(io.StringIO(text), ...)`. BTW: `read_csv` and `read_excel` can read from file, or file-like object (like `io.StringIO`) or even from `url` - `read_csv("https://...", ...)`

Comment: Perfect, and how to tabulate?

Comment: load your file as before - with all your settings, not mine.